# jquery update data-attribute based on another data-attribute value in same a:link and text

Tags: jquery

I have the following line of HTML and I need to update the data-colour and text values based on the value that matches the data-id value

```
<td class="colour"><a class="btn btn-link btn-sm btnModal" role="button" id="product-1" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-id="123" data-colour=""><img src="/colourWheel.png">Select colour</a></td>
```

From the code below, I have removed most that is not relevant

```
$(".colour-code").on("click",function() {
        var colour = $(this).data("product");
        var id = $(this).data("id");
    });
```

var id will equal data-id="123" so I need to add the value of var colour to data-colour="" and also update the text.

**The problem I have is that $(".colour-code").on("click",function() is in a modal** so I'm unable to use closest

Comment: where the element that have class `colour-code`, i can not see here.

Answer (score 0):

Been a long day, all I needed to do was

```
 $("#product-1 span").text(colour);
 $("#product-1").attr("data-colour",colour);
```

:(